# How preserve just read permission from an original file to a symlink?

Tags: linux, shell-script, directory, symlink, file-copy

I make a copy file, from directory A, as a symlink in directory B and I need to preserve just the read permission from original file  to symlink.
like this example: original file have `–rwx-wxr-x`, link should have `–r-----r--`

I need to do this in code C in linux, not command.I guess  is  something with umask but I dont't know how is it.

Answer (score 4):

Symlinks have no concept of permissions, so you can't enforce different permissions when passing through a symlink than that which you would get accessing the eventual file. They essentially just store a path that leads to some other file (or doesn't, since symlinks can dangle).

The reason symlinks themselves have no concept of permission is because it's hard to come up with any use case to do so: if one can dereference a symlink and successfully access the eventual file, they could just as well have used `readlink`(2) on the symlink and just read the eventual file with its original permissions. As such, the simplest and most reasonable answer is "you can't". :-)

If you're determined to do this, one option is to use eBPF, ptrace, or similar to intercept calls to that file path and fake some permissions (although you may have to pretend it isn't a symlink to avoid provoking weird states in programs which rightly never expected this to be a problem). Again, if you have a symlink, people are just going to be resolve it to its final destination, so I'm not sure what you're hoping to achieve here.

Comment: Can you set some permissions on the folder containing the symlink to prevent access to the link for unpermitted users and accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @LeeMeador The OP asks that the link should be visible, but read-only. That's not possible to achieve through directory permissions.